# In C# How to read data from table and after some calculation save those data in another table?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I an new in C#. I am trying to read data from a table named 'tblAddResult'. In this table I have some columns and I want to make average of 3 columns of tblAddResult and save it to a new table named `tblResult`.

Some other calculations also wanna do there like Taking 50% of a data of a column of `tblAddResult`.

I did this in this way(code placed below) but I am getting an error "invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed". I don't even know if this is the right way to do it if not can anyone help me with the write way or any suggestions regarding this way. I am really helpless for this problem.

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT   tblAddResult.* FROM  tblAddResult", con);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (sdr.Read())
        {

            String subject = sdr.GetString(2);
            int january = sdr.GetInt32(3);
            int february = sdr.GetInt32(4);
            int march = sdr.GetInt32(5);
            int average = (january + february + march) / 3;
            int average40= average*40/(100);
            int marks = sdr.GetInt32(6);
            int marks50 = marks * 50 / 100;
            int WorkingDay = sdr.GetInt32(7);
            int Attandence = sdr.GetInt32(8);
            int Attendence10 = Attandence * 10 / 100;
            int totalMarks = average40 + marks50 + Attendence10;
            string grade = "" ;
            if (totalMarks < 51) { grade = "C"; }
            else if (totalMarks < 61) { grade = "B"; }
            else if (totalMarks < 71) { grade = "A-"; }
            else if (totalMarks < 81) { grade = "A"; }
            else if (totalMarks < 91) { grade = "A+"; }
            else if (totalMarks <= 100) { grade = "A++"; }
            con.Close();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand comnd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblResult (Subject, [Full Marks], January, February, March, [Average Class Perfomance], [Earned Marks], [Working Day], Attendence, [Cls Attendence(40%)], [Exam Perfomance(50%)], [Attendence(10%)], [Marks(%)], Grade)VALUES  ('"+subject+"','"+"100"+"','"+january+"','"+february+"','"+march+"','"+average+"','"+marks+"','"+WorkingDay+"','"+Attandence+"','"+average40+"','"+marks50+"','"+Attendence10+"','"+totalMarks+"','"+grade+"')",con);
            comnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Successfull!");

        }
```

Comment: You don't need to close and reopen the connection inside your while loop

Comment: Also, do you REALLY want that MessageBox to pop up inside the loop? It would show "Successful" for every row you update this way.... Second: Please parameterize your queries. Last but not least: Have a look at the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), it makes life much easier. :D

Comment: I use MessageBox to make sure is it working.And If i dont open and close the connection it shows "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." But using open and close my first row is being saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the code like below, for better safety. The error occurred because DataReader operations will work only when in the Opened Connection state.

```
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT tblAddResult.* FROM  tblAddResult", con);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);//this will close the DataReader along with Connection close.

        while (sdr.Read())
        {

            String subject = sdr.GetString(2);
            int january = sdr.GetInt32(3);
            int february = sdr.GetInt32(4);
            int march = sdr.GetInt32(5);
            int average = (january + february + march) / 3;
            int average40= average*40/(100);
            int marks = sdr.GetInt32(6);
            int marks50 = marks * 50 / 100;
            int WorkingDay = sdr.GetInt32(7);
            int Attandence = sdr.GetInt32(8);
            int Attendence10 = Attandence * 10 / 100;
            int totalMarks = average40 + marks50 + Attendence10;
            string grade = "" ;
            if (totalMarks < 51) { grade = "C"; }
            else if (totalMarks < 61) { grade = "B"; }
            else if (totalMarks < 71) { grade = "A-"; }
            else if (totalMarks < 81) { grade = "A"; }
            else if (totalMarks < 91) { grade = "A+"; }
            else if (totalMarks <= 100) { grade = "A++"; }

            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblResult (Subject, [Full Marks], January, February, March, [Average Class Perfomance], [Earned Marks], [Working Day], Attendence, [Cls Attendence(40%)], [Exam Perfomance(50%)], [Attendence(10%)], [Marks(%)], Grade)VALUES  ('"+subject+"','"+"100"+"','"+january+"','"+february+"','"+march+"','"+average+"','"+marks+"','"+WorkingDay+"','"+Attandence+"','"+average40+"','"+marks50+"','"+Attendence10+"','"+totalMarks+"','"+grade+"')",con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();           

        }
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Successfull!");
```

EDIT:

Instead of using DataReader approach, use DataTable and an example is given to you below.  Hope it will help.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM  Test_Table1", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow sdr in dt.Rows)
            {
                String subject = sdr[0].ToString();
                int january = Convert.ToInt32(sdr[1]);
                int february = Convert.ToInt32(sdr[2]);
                int march = 0;
                int average = (january + february + march) / 3;
                int average40 = average * 40 / (100);

                cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Test_Table2 (Test_Col1, Test_Col2) VALUES  ('" + subject + "'," + average40 + ")", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: It Shows 
Error :The name 'CommandBehaviour' does not exist in the current context.
Is there any namespace i need for it?

Comment: refer the corrected one, the correct spelling is CommandBehavior which will also come from System.Data namespace

Comment: Still the same error regarding this line of code
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();      
ERROR:There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Comment: Sir,
 **Sai Kalyan Kumar Akshinthala**, If u really understand my problem,can u suggest me with another way of doing this.I think its not the way what i am going to do.As i am a beginner so this problem is making me sick i am stuck with this problem for more than one 1 week. :(

Comment: Yes got the problem, will give you a solution asap

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation

Comment: @Bashar, check with the Edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You recieve this error because you close the connection before the reader is returned/finished. Delete the two lines `con.Close();` and `con.Open();` and clsoe the connection after the reader finished (ie, outside the while-loop).

Comment: For 
         comnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
If i dont open and close the connection it shows "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."